# How to execute scrapy python in a javascript file?

Tags: python, node.js, scrapy

I have a `python` script that I launched with the command `scrapy crawl mynamefile`.

I would like to run the `python` cli command `scrapy crawl` from a `js` file in my `node js` application, then display it in the console.

The problem is that I don't how to import the `scrapy` `python` library in node.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please, provide your code examples for both js/python, but anyway, you can check this guide https://medium.com/@HolmesLaurence/integrating-node-and-python-6b8454bfc272

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a good idea to run Python code from NodeJS. If you are for some reason forced to do that, you probably need to call Python script in a child process (see for example [this article](https://medium.com/@HolmesLaurence/integrating-node-and-python-6b8454bfc272)).

Alternatively, you might use something like [Scrapyrt](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyrt), which exposes HTTP API for your Scrapy project and provides on-demand scraping ability.

Yet the best option seems to be using some native JavaScript scraping solution, like [Apify](https://sdk.apify.com/).